# Оптимизация алгоритма нахождения количества компонент связности

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Всем привет! Необходимо реализовать следующее:
Вводится n, количество вершин в графе
m количество рёбер
Дальше идет m строк, описывающее ребра графа 
Потом идет число q
А дальше q чисел в одной строке, которые указывают, какие из рёбер, которые были описаны выше, удалены. 
Необходимо найти количество компонент связности (извините, если неправильно употребил склонение слов)
Вот код:

```
ans = 0
r_ans = ''


def obhod(versh, net):
    global visited_map, n
    if visited_map[versh]:
        return False
    visited_map[versh] = True
    if max(net[versh]) == 0:
        return True
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if net[versh][i] == 1 and not visited_map[i]:
            if min(visited_map):
                return
            obhod(i, net)
    return True

n = int(input())
m = int(input())
wires = []


for w in range(m):
    wr = list(map(int, input().split(' ')))
    wires.append(wr)

q = int(input())
que = list(map(int, input().split(' ')))

for j in range(q):
    visited_map = [True] + [False] * n
    net = []
    for ne in range(n+1):
        net.append([0] * (n+1))
    for i in range(m):
        if i+1 in que[:j+1]:
            continue
        net[wires[i][0]][wires[i][1]] = 1
        net[wires[i][1]][wires[i][0]] = 1
    for v in range(1, n+1):
        if obhod(v, net):
            ans += 1
        if min(visited_map):
            break
    r_ans += str(ans) + ' '
    ans = 0

print(r_ans)
```

Но он работает слишком долго. Что можно попробовать с этим сделать?
Вот примеры входных данных:

```
Sample Input 1:
3
3
1 2
2 3
1 3
2
1 2
Sample Output 1:
1 2
Sample Input 2:
4
3
1 2
1 4
4 2
1
3
Sample Output 2:
2
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем краткий ответ - ваш алгоритм работает порядка MQ что слишком много. Правильное решение делается за N+M+Q (линейно от входных данных).

Вам нужно сначала удалить все рёбра которые нужно будет удалять. Выполнить обход. Получить ответ. Это будет ответ для последнего ввода. Дальше добавлять с конца по 1 ребру используя систему непересекающихся множеств (она работает за O(1) амортизировано, не забудьте использовать обе эвристики).

Собственно алгоритма лучше по сложности не будет.

Comment: А можно поподробнее про "систему непересекающихся множеств"?

Comment: @vladF http://e-maxx.ru/algo/dsu

Comment: @vladF перечитал статью, тут даже описано прямо решение этой задачи, впрочем тоже самое что и я написал.